# What is the fetch_array equivelant in prepared statements?

Tags: php, pdo

I use `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` with `query` but it doesn't work with prepared statements. What is the equivalent of that in prepared statements?

Comment: `bind_result` and `get_result`

Comment: **WHAT API you are using? mysqli or PDO?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$query = "SELECT `users` FROM `table` WHERE `country` = :country";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(
   ':country' => $country
));

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Here you define how results are fetched
```

or you can define default `FETCH MODE` to be an associate array, like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = $stmt->fetch(); // The same thing now
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted PDO solution, here is one for mysqli:

The first thing to keep in mind is that mysqli prepared statements do *not* require results to be bound:

> Instead of using bound results, results can also be retrieved through the mysqli_result interface. mysqli_stmt_get_result() returns a buffered result set.

So, for example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY column LIMIT ?,' . SOME_CONSTANT;
```

Once you have bound and executed your statement, you can call get_result():

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $int) || die($db->error);
$stmt->execute()             || die($db->error);
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

At this point we are functionally equivalent to:

```
if ($result = $db->query($sql)) {
```

And can call our familiar fetch_array:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Instead of closing the result as we would in the non-prepared equivalent, we close the statement:

```
$stmt->close();
```